# Opencv build error with C1083

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I am building Opencv in Windows with Vs2013. I have configured and generated using CMAKE.
Now the OPENCV solution is opened and tried to build with VS2013.
I have a lot of errors for not finding the header files. Actually the header files are there inside the folder "`C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\opencv\build\include\opencv2`"

The errors are shown in the attached image.
[image]

What could be wrong?

EDIT:

I used CMake GUI as shown in the image.
[image]

Comment: Show how you have configured OpenCV (source and binary directories, which options you have passed to CMake).

Comment: @Tsyvarev i have added Cmake GUI. Most of them are default.